Chrome Vue.js devtools v6.6.3 not showing getters of root store (Vuex)
I have a root store with states, mutations and getters. It also exports modules (sub stores). When inspecting it in chrome Vue.js devtools v6.6.3 it only shows the modules. I don't see any states or getters related to the root store itself. Is there an obvious error in this example?
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

export default createStore({
  modules: {
    someSubStore,
  },

  state: {
    myItems: {
      items: [],
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_ITEMS: (state, items) => {
      state.myItems.items = items
    },
  },

  actions: {
    loadItems: ({ commit, dispatch }) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(`/api/items`).then(
          ({ data }) => {
            commit('SET_ITEMS', data)
            resolve(data)
          },
          ({ response }) => {
            reject(response)
          },
        )
      })
    },
  },

  getters: {
    myItems: (state) => state.myItems.items,
  },
})

I tried to inspect this in Chrome Vue.js devtools v6.6.3 and I am expecting to also be able to see the states and getters of the root store.

What versions of Vue and Vuex? No obvious error that I see. In this case it might be helpful to include a screenshot of what you see in Vue devtools.  You should see a hierarchy view of your store with ability to click "Root" or store module underneath.  Make sure "Root" is selected if it's there.
